# Kivy: why is pop-up window semi-transparent?

Tags: python, popup, kivy

To whom it may concern,

I am adding pop-up windows in my Kivy/Python application.  At first I was using the example provided in kivy.org pages: http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.popup.html#module-kivy.uix.popup which was OK, but I wanted a more elegant solution, with kivy files.

So I found one example in: examples\widgets\popup_with_kv.py, which is fine, but when I use it, as it is, it creates semi-transparent pop-up windows.

Does anyone know why?

Maybe someone has encountered the same issue before.

Comment: I ran the example but don't see a problem. Can you give an example program demonstrating the issue?

Answer (score 1):

`Popup`s inherit from `ModalView` which has a default `background_color` of `[0, 0, 0, .7]`, referring to the [r, g, b, a] values. The **.7** is the alpha of the  background. Perhaps this accounts for what you are seeing. Try changing the `background_color` alpha value to 1 if you want an opaque background.

**Note:** 
Unless you size your popup to be smaller than it's default size_hint(1,1), then this just shouldn't be an issue. The most of the actual background you would see in this default case is a thin line just around the edges, as your popup content(even if you don't set one a sort of dull grey blankness will be before you) will take up the entire screen.

So I am assuming that you have scaled the popup down from it's default size, as that's when you actually see the background that 'background_color' refers to.